# Let $f=X^4-1$ and $g=X^3+X$ be polynomials in $\Bbb Z[X]$. Find some $h \in \Bbb Z[X]$ for which $\langle h \rangle = \langle f,g \rangle.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $f=X^4-1$ and $g=X^3+X$ be polynomials in $\Bbb Z[X]$ and let $\langle f, g\rangle$ be the ideal generated by $f$ and $g$. Find some $h \in \Bbb Z[X]$ for which $$\langle h \rangle = \langle f,g \rangle.$$

Performing long division on $X^4-1$ by $X^3+X$ I obtained that $$(X^4-1)-X(X^3+X)=-X^2-1$$ so I think that $-X^2-1$ should work for $h$ in this case. However I cannot show that $$\langle -X^2-1\rangle = \langle X^4-1, X^3+X\rangle.$$

If $p \in \langle -X^2-1\rangle$, then $p(X)=q(X)(-X^2-1)$ for some $q \in \Bbb Z[X]$, but how can I show that $p(X) = a(X)(X^4-1)+ b(X)(X^3+X)$ for $a,b \in \Bbb Z[X]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the key equation right there in your question!

$$ -X^2 - 1 = (X^4 - 1) - X(X^3 + X)$$

So for any $p(X) = q(X)(-X^2 - 1)$, we have

$$ p(X) = q(X)\cdot ((X^4 - 1) - X(X^3 + X))$$
$$ = q(X) (X^4 - 1) + (-X q(X)) (X^3 + X)$$

as desired.